# I cannot install Docker Desktop 2.3.0.2 on my Windows Home machine. My machine is up to date

Tags: windows, docker

I think those who have this problem are installing Docker Toolbox.
I could not access the installation files.
How do I install Docker Toolbox on Windows Home?

The error I got:

> Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise (15063+) or Windows
>   10 Home (19018+).

Comment: Please check your version , whether it is `19018+`.

Comment: execute `winver` command and tell us your windows version

Comment: windows version 18363

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can follow to install Docker Toolbox on Windows 10 Home. I am running it on my Windows 10 Home Version 1909 (OS build 18363) too and it works like a charm

https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Answer (score 0):

The windows update is not showing in windows update. You can get the latest update from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10